# Pixel counting and mode for classification refinement in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, javascript, classification, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

Currently I am trying to refine a *Classification* for year 2001 based on the class persistence during a 3 year window: maps of 2000, 2001 and 2002.

My two rules are:

1. If in the 3 years period there were only 2 classes; remap 2001 to the mode of the three years;
2. If each class value is unique for each year, maintain the value of 2001.

I managed to figure out the first rule in my code, but since there are NO MODE for unique values, I need to figure out a way to maintain the value of 2001. But I can't figure out how.

[image: Text]

```
var y2000 = ee.Image("users/celiohelder/Liberia/LandCoverMaps/AnnualV2/Y2000")
var y2001 = ee.Image("users/celiohelder/Liberia/LandCoverMaps/AnnualV2/Y2001")
var y2002 = ee.Image("users/celiohelder/Liberia/LandCoverMaps/AnnualV2/Y2002")

var allImages = ee.ImageCollection([y2000.set('year',2000),y2001.set('year',2001),y2002.set('year',2002)])

var yearseq = ee.List([2001]);

var threeYearAvg = ee.ImageCollection(yearseq.map(function(y){
    var yNum = ee.Number(y).int()
    var ycurr = ee.Image(allImages
                .filterMetadata('year', 'equals', yNum).select('remapped').sum());
    var yprev1 = ee.Image(allImages
                .filterMetadata('year', 'equals', yNum.subtract(1)).select('remapped').sum());
    var yfwd1 = ee.Image(allImages
                .filterMetadata('year', 'equals', yNum.add(1)).select('remapped').sum());
    var getMode = ee.ImageCollection([ycurr, yprev1, yfwd1]).mode() 
    var test = ycurr.where(getMode.neq(ycurr),getMode)

    return test. addBands(getMode.neq(ycurr).rename('flag'))
}));


print(threeYearAvg.select('remapped'))

Map.addLayer(threeYearAvg.select('remapped'),{min:1, max:11, palette: paletteNASANEW_all},'Refined Map')
Map.addLayer(threeYearAvg.select('flag'),{min:0, max:1, palette: ['white','black']},'Change Flag')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way of obtaining the desired output using the `countDistinct` reducer to count the number of distinct values per pixel in the collection of images. Afterwards, use this image to set different values to the final image according to the following rules: 1) stay with `ycurr` value if 3 unique values are counted, or if not, substitute with the mode.

```
var threeYearAvg = ee.ImageCollection(yearseq.map(function(y){
    var yNum = ee.Number(y).int();
    var ycurr = ee.Image(allImages
                .filterMetadata('year', 'equals', yNum).select('remapped').sum());
    var yprev1 = ee.Image(allImages
                .filterMetadata('year', 'equals', yNum.subtract(1)).select('remapped').sum());
    var yfwd1 = ee.Image(allImages
                .filterMetadata('year', 'equals', yNum.add(1)).select('remapped').sum());
    
    // No changes until here
    //Create collection from 3 images            
    var images3Col = ee.ImageCollection([ycurr, yprev1, yfwd1]);            
    // Count distinct values
    var countDistinct = images3Col.reduce(ee.Reducer.countDistinct());
    // If countDistinct less than 2 substitute with the mode of the 3 images
    // If not stay with the ycurr value
    var resul = ycurr.where(countDistinct.lt(2), images3Col.mode());
    
    // Return resul
    return resul.rename('remapped')
                .addBands(countDistinct.rename('flag'));
}));
```

Comment: Thank you so much Jonathan. That was very helpful! I appreciate it.